# React Native onPress function keeps getting called

Tags: react-native, onpress

I'm trying to run a function in react native where a function gets called when the button is pressed but when the button is pressed once the function keeps running over and over again.  How do I fix the code to make this not happen. The add_password function is the function that keeps getting called

```
function DetailsScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [text3, setText3] = useState("");
  const [text4, setText4] = useState("");
  const { param1, param2 } = route.params;

  let button_click = () => {
    add_password(text3, text4, param1, param2);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40 }}
        placeholder="info"
        onChangeText={(text3) => setText3(text3)}
        defaultValue={text3}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40 }}
        placeholder="password"
        onChangeText={(text4) => setText4(text4)}
        defaultValue={text4}
      />
      <Button title="Add Password" onPress={button_click} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, I got your code from github repo and then, to test it, I used [react-native-expo-gitpod](https://github.com/jayfresh/react-native-expo-gitpod). It's just an empty project that could be runned on gitpod. Then I pasted your code from github repo in App.js and runned it. I made the login in `HomeScreen`:

[image]

Then I filled `Details` info and password fields:

[image]

Then I clicked `Add Password` button. And the result was that `button_click` function is called just one time!

This is `DetailsScreen` code:

```
function DetailsScreen({ navigation, route }) {
  const [text3, setText3] = useState("");
  const [text4, setText4] = useState("");
  const { param1, param2 } = route.params;

  const button_click = () => {
      console.log("button_click");
    add_password(text3, text4, param1, param2);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40 }}
        placeholder="info"
        onChangeText={(text3) => setText3(text3)}
        defaultValue={text3}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{ height: 40 }}
        placeholder="password"
        onChangeText={(text4) => setText4(text4)}
        defaultValue={text4}
      />
      <Button
        title="Add Password"
        onPress={button_click} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Exactly like yours (except the log to check how many times function is called).

The log I received is:

[image]

`calling add_password` is another log that I putted in `add_password` function.

Seems that all is working well!

Note: this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start -c --host tunnel",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "~3.0.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/web": "^1.0.0-alpha.9",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "^7.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^7.0.0",
    "expo-font": "^7.0.0",
    "expo-web-browser": "^7.0.0",
    "firebase": "^7.17.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^3.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^35.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I changed it and that did not work it's still running continuously after 1 press.

Comment: Ciao, what a strange... can you show me `add_password` function?

Comment: it won't let me put the function in a comment because it's too long but the function isn't the problem it's that it's being called continuously. The add password function just makes changes to an entry in the database.

Comment: Sorry, seems so natural that this function must be called just one time onPress event. I tried to reproduce the error [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-feynman-vizur?file=/src/App.js) but it worked (I'm using react-native-web and could be different but I mean it's just a button click!). Can you share a github repo so I can check here?

Comment: here is a link to the repo https://github.com/RobertBeit/Vault I excluded the firebase config for security reasons

Comment: Ciao @RobertBeit, I just tried your solution. Unfortunately is not exaclty identical to your code (I can't run add_password as is because I haven't firebase config, and for the same reason I can't log in from Home screen). So I have  just moved `Add password` button from `DetailsScreen` to `HomeScreen` and in `button_click` I put a console.log (removing `add_password`). Function is called just one time. I saw `add_password` function and looks ok. How I can continue to help you? Maybe you could create a private github repo with firebase config if you trust. Let me know.

Comment: I made the repo private and included the config. https://github.com/RobertBeit/Vault

Comment: Ciao, invite me on repo, I'm gioexp

Comment: Ciao @RobertBeit, I got 404 page not found when I clicked on [https://github.com/RobertBeit/Vault](https://github.com/RobertBeit/Vault)

Comment: I invited you. You should be able to access it now.

Comment: Ciao @RobertBeit. I rewrited my answer. I Hope this could help you.